# Powershell: Installing Custom-Module with Install-Module

Tags: powershell

I have written a Powershell module. I would like to use this permanently. I understand that an `Import-Module` keeps the module in memory only during the session and is volatile.

It becomes persistent only by `Install-Module`. Unfortunately, Powershell expects a repository. I don't have that. Although I could manually copy the module to the module directory by determinating the path with `$env:Path`. But this is not nice.

Is there a "clean" way to install a custom module using `Install-Module`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It becomes persistent only by `Install-Module`

This is only because `Install-Module` copies the module to one of the locations in `$env:PSModulePath`. It doesn't do anything clever to made the module persistent.

PowerShell reads the module manifests (`.psd1` files) in those locations and any functions in the `FunctionsToExport` will be available.

When you try to use one of those functions, PowerShell will import that module.
You can test this out by running `Get-Module` before and after using a function from an unloaded module.
You can also test the fact that it has to import the module by adding a `throw` to the top of your `.psm1` file - trying to use a function from that module will give you:

> Custom-Command : The 'Custom-Command' command was found in the module 'Custom-Module', but the module could not be loaded.
> For more information, run 'Import-Module Custom-Module'.

---

> Unfortunately, Powershell expects a repository. I don't have that

You can create one.

```
$customModulePath = 'C:\Temp\Modules\Custom-Module'
$repoPath = 'C:\Temp\LocalRepo'
New-Item -Path $repoPath -ItemType Directory

$repoParameters = @{
    Name               = 'LocalRepo'
    SourceLocation     = $repoPath
    PublishLocation    = $repoPath
    InstallationPolicy = 'Trusted'
}
Register-PSRepository @repoParameters
Publish-Module -Path $customModulePath -Repository LocalRepo
Install-Module Custom-Module -Repository LocalRepo
```

- `Publish-Module` will do some validation on your module and fail if it sees anything it doesn't like.
- `Publish-Module` will create a zip of you module in `$repoPath` - you can open it using 7zip etc
- `Install-Module` will install in the `AllUsers` scope by default if it can (running as admin) and `CurrentUser` if it can't. You can use the `-Scope` parameter to override this.
- As detailed in [`Install-module` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-5.1):
  `AllUsers` path: `$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\Modules`
  `CurrentUser` path: `$home\Documents\PowerShell\Modules`

Your module will be in one of the paths above, exactly as if you had copied it. The only difference will be an additional (hidden) `PSGetModuleInfo.xml` file. This has information related to the module package and repository.

---

> Although I could manually copy the module to the module directory by determinating the path with `$env:Path`. But this is not nice.

I think this is a viable option, using one of the paths above, as that's the part of `Install-Module` that gives you persistence.

Another way is to modify your `$profile` to import the module at start or add your module directory to `$env:PSModulePath`. I use the second one so I can keep my modules in my repo with the rest of my code.

- `Import-Module 'C:\Temp\Modules\Custom-Module'`
- `$env:PSModulePath += ';C:\Temp\Modules\'`

---

> Is there a "clean" way to install a custom module using Install-Module?

If by "clean" you mean `Install-Module 'C:\Temp\Modules\Custom-Module'`, then no - that's not what `Install-Module` is designed for.
If you're after module persistence, that's a yes.

Comment: wow this seems like a lot more work than `npm install -g` for my custom node script.

Answer (score 1):

you can store the module manually in one of the modules paths.

the variable `$Env:PSModulePath` shows the paths powershell looks for modules.

you can store the moduel for your account only at `%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

for reference the documentaion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want. But I understand there seems only two options:
1. Installing manually
2. Using a Repository